# How to get top k accuracy in semantic segmentation using PyTorch?

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

How do you compute the top k accuracy in semantic segmentation? In classification, we might compute the topk accuracy as:

```py
correct = output.eq(gt.view(1, -1).expand_as(output))
```

Comment: for normal classification you can check this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/imagenet-example-accuracy-calculation/7840/9?u=brando_miranda does that help? How is it different for segmentation?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`torch.topk`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.topk) function that computes the top k values along a dimension.
The second output of `torch.topk` is the "arg top k": the k indices of the top values.

Here's how this can be used in the context of semantic segmentation:
Suppose you have the ground truth prediction tensor `y` of shape `b`-`h`-`w` (dtype=`torch.int64`).
Your model predicts per-pixel class `logits` of shape `b`-`c`-`h`-`w`, with `c` is the number of classes (including "background"). These logits are the "raw" predictions *before* `softmax` function transforms them into class probabilities.
Since we are only looking at the top `k`, it does not matter if the predictions are "raw" or "probabilities".

```py
# compute the top k predicted classes, per pixel:
_, tk = torch.topk(logits, k, dim=1)
# you now have k predictions per pixel, and you want that one of them will match the true labels y:
correct_pixels = torch.eq(y[:, None, ...], tk).any(dim=1)
# take the mean of correct_pixels to get the overall average top-k accuracy:
top_k_acc = correct_pixels.mean()
```

Note that this method does not take into account "ignore" pixels. This can be done with a slight modification to the above code:

```py
valid = y != ignore_index
top_k_acc = correct_pixels[valid].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output is a series of scores ordered as per your list of classes `labels`:

```
import torch

scores, indices = torch.topk(output, k)
correct = labels[indices]
```